# How to have multiple exclusions using /:p ExcludeObjectTypes

Tags: t-sql, dacpac, sqlpackage

Keeping it simple, this is the piece of code Im having an issue with

```
.\SqlPackage.exe /Action:Script 
/SourceFile:"$outputDirectory\$outputDacpacFile" 
/TargetServerName:$targetServer /TargetDatabaseName:$targetDatabase 
/TargetUser:$targetUser /TargetPassword:$targetPassword 
/OutputPath:"$outputDirectory\$outputTSQLfile" 
/p:ExcludeObjectTypes=DatabaseRoles;Users
```

The ExcludeObjectTypes seems to only process whatever appears first after the =. So if I put =Users, it will get rid of the users from the Tsql script and if I enter =DatabaseRoles then it will get rid of the roles. I cant seem to get them to work together. I've tried adding another /p:ExcludeObjectTypes (one for DatabaseRoles and one for Users) but I get an error mentioning that ive entered a duplicate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon `;` may be treated as a command terminator symbol in CMD or Powershell. You can pass multiple object types by setting `/p:ExcludeObjectType` (not plural) multiple times in command line e.g:

```
... /p:ExcludeObjectType=DatabaseRoles /p:ExcludeObjectType=Users ...
```

or try with quotes around object types list.